# Java - Want to convert an Integer Value type to a Byte, so I can write to a file in binary format

Tags: java, string, arrays

I'm trying to convert an Integer (32 bits or 4 Bytes) to a Byte array and write to a file ONLY the first Byte of that integer truncated.

```
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileChooser.getSelectedFile() + ".soit"));

byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(511).array();
for (byte b : bytes) {
    System.out.format("0x%x ", b);
    try {
        os.write(bytes, 0, 1);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(p8r_planning.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Here's a snippet of my code, which sadly creates the file but does not contain any data, however my System.out.format line, does print out the expected results.

0x0 0x0 0x1 0xff

in this case, I only want the very first byte (0xff) written to my file in binary format.
Like this:

11111111

Can someone point to me what I might have done wrong?

Comment: If you only want 1 byte, why are multiple being written (eg. why is the loop being used)? Also, it appears you really want to write "the X [binary?] representation of a byte value, as text"..?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `writeInt` on `DataOutputStream` which write it as big endian

```
try (DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(
                           new FileOutputStream(
                               fileChooser.getSelectedFile() + ".soit"))) {
   os.writeByte((byte) 511); // write just the lowest 8-bits.
}
```

Comment: But that will write 4 Bytes. How would I only get the first Byte?

Comment: This method does not exist in my version of java

Comment: @daemoner119 my mistake, I have corrected it.There is a readUnsignedByte() but not a write of the same.